Refused a visa to Hungary
I asked a couple of months ago about whether to apply for a visa at the Hungarian or Italian consulate (my main purpose of visit was a conference in Hungary that I was invited to, but since I decided upon travelling a bit afterwards I was staying a day longer in Italy). I was advised to apply at the Hungarian consulate. (I even emailed the Hungarian consulate about it but never got a reply).
I went there today and the fellow straight out dismissed my application saying since I am staying in Italy longer, tourism is my main purpose of visiting. So I'm curious, is there any individual who got a Schengen visa for country A where the purpose was business and then spent more time at country B for whatever reasons? Or was I simply misled?
Or was this an individual scenario where the fellow in the consulate was simply incompetent?

The consulate employee misapplied the Schengen "Main Destination" idea: even though you were planning to stay longer in Italy than in Hungary, your main destination was the conference in Hungary — you wouldn't have been going to Europe otherwise. The Answer of @o.m. in this recent Travel.SE question addresses the "Main Destination" issue.

It is sadly quite a common scenario, especially when applications go through a third party like VFS (but apparently in some consulates as well). The Schengen Visa code very clearly states (article 5): "the main destination of the visit(s) in terms of the length of stay, counted in days, or the purpose of stay" (emphasis mine), but for some reason, many will only consider the first option.

Op switched his travel plans though so it's simply possible that they changed what they usually define by main destination etc. it's simply so infuriating because now I have to miss the conference, and will lose considerable amount of money from all the accomodations I had to make to apply for said visa.

When is your conference, and what country are you in? If you went there today to apply surely you can still go apply to the Italian consulate as well in time? Though don't be surprised if they tell you "no, you need to apply at the Hungarian consulate, because that is the main purpose for your visit" :-(

@Pablo You still have the option of shortening the tourism in Italy part to make sure you fit into the pattern they "want". Either shorten the whole trip, or spend more time in Hungary and less in Italy, or even split the time among more countries, as long as you have more time in Hungary than in any other.

Condition In Law | UpCounsel 2023 A disjunctive condition [or] is one that provides one or two Alternatives to the performance under the contract. Nothing states that the second option takes priority over the first. ("the main destination of the visit(s) in terms of the length of stay, counted in days, or the purpose of stay")

@MarkJohnson nobody is saying that the second option takes priority, just that either condition being met should be sufficient for the consulate to accept the application. Of course their interpretation is that the main purpose is the purpose that uses the most days, but then just stating length of stay would be enough, so that was clearly not the intent.

@jcaron Doubtful. The first condition takes priority. In the case when the amount of days in Italy and Hungary are the same, then the second condition comes into play.

Welp the website for Netherlands is saying this Example: business travel and holiday
If you are travelling to the Netherlands for business and want to holiday in Sweden before or after, your business trip is the main reason for your stay in the Schengen area. You should apply for a visa for the Netherlands, even if your stay in Sweden will be longer

Under the assumption that this link is legit https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/visa-the-netherlands/visiting-more-than-one-schengen-country

@MarkJohnson That's very doubtful. This would give applicants an easy way to forum shop for a specific consulate by extending their stay in a country of their choice. You can also see that when the EU legislator wants to establish a priority they do it explicitly as it did with the three clauses in this article. And obviously, some random US source about “contracts” isn't particularly relevant, especially if you consider that EU law is written in multiple languages and you know a little bit about the way the EUCJ goes about interpreting it.

Technically I think your application was ‘rejected’, not refused. A very important terminology distinction, assuming I’m correct.

Schengen visa is a mess in my opinion, the harmonisation of the visa code does not work and each embassy has its own interpretation of the code. Eventually you get a Schengen Visa and you can go anywhere and in my personal experiences I have seen people doing that and it’s know as visa shopping. The problem is complex.
